# What are the maximum values accepted by .limit() method and $limit aggregation operation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to know the maximum allowed values by the `cursor.limit()` method and `$limit` aggregation pipeline stage by `mongodb 3.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.limit/) for `cursor.limit()`:

> The behavior of limit() is undefined for values less than -2^31 and greater than 2^31

So, we can infer that 2^31 is the maximum value.

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) for `$limit`:

> $limit takes a positive integer that specifies the maximum number of documents to pass along.

So, I *think* we can infer that 2^31 is the maximum value there too. Though perhaps `$limit` is a 64-bit integer in which case the maximum value is: 2^63. The docs are unclear on this point.

Update based on feedback from @AyushGupta:

> So I just checked, 2^63 is too high for $limit when written as a number and not an exponential. 9223372036854775295 is $limit's upper limit it seems from what i could test

Of course, any usage of `limit()` has an effective (rather than theoretical) maximum too, namely; the total number of documents in the collection you are querying. So, if your collection has < 2,147,483,647 documents then the maximum value of limit is probably moot :)

Comment: Thanks, any idea about $limit by any chance?

Comment: I'm not sure about the second part, I tried a value much greater than 2^31 this morning for $limit and it worked. Going by the scheme though, I'll try 2^63 as soon as I can.

Comment: @AyushGupta That's possible, I have updated the answer to add some more info on this point.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking the same. In any case, I'll check it tomorrow when I have access to my work PC.

Comment: Honestly though I was looking for the common maximum value which can be passed to both .limit() and $limit. Looks like 2^31 is the way to go

Comment: Do you actually have more than 2^31 docs at play? Such a large number doesn't feel like a 'limit' :) Anyway, if you need _some_ value for 'maxiumum limit' then 2^31 seems safe since it is supported by both `limit()` and `$limit`.

Comment: I just want to get all elements in a collection in the specific scenario. Some of my db queries use  .limit() while some use $limit. So I'll just pass 2^31 as the limit. Think of it as bypassing the limit ;)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense

Comment: So I just checked, 2^63 is too high for $limit when written as a number and not an exponential. 9223372036854775295 is $limit's upper limit it seems from what i could test

Comment: @AyushGupta I've added your last comment to the answer (crediting you) so that this empirically discovered number can be more easily found by anyone looking in future. Thanks.